# How to send a json script as a file to groovy

Tags: json, groovy

Below is my JSON script.
**PRAMS.json**

```
{
    "JSON" : {
        "test": "iTEST",
        "testname": "BOV-VDSL-link-Rateprofile-CLI-Test-1",
        "params": [
            {
                "n2x_variables / config_file": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Agilent/N2X/RouterTester900/UserData/config/7.30 EA SP1 Release/OSP  Regression/BOV/Bov-data-1-single-rate-profile.xml"
            },
            {
                "n2x_variables / port_list": "303/4 303/1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Below is my groovy script and I am sending **params.json** script to the same groovy script.

parseJSON.groovy

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonFile = new File("../var/PARAMS.json")
def keys = new JsonSlurper().parse("jsonFile.text")
println keys.keySet()
```

I am getting below error :

```
****No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [jsonFile.text]****
```

Can any one please help me ?

Thanks for reply, I am new to this json.

I am unable to share screen shot, showing error message when I am trying to upload image but i can give total error message :

```
developer@cn-vm-yourname:~/Desktop/kramdeni/vars$ groovy parseJSON.groovy

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [jsonFile]
Possible solutions: parse(java.io.Reader), parseText(java.lang.String), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait(), grep(), any()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [jsonFile]
Possible solutions: parse(java.io.Reader), parseText(java.lang.String), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait(), grep(), any()
at parseJSON.run(parseJSON.groovy:3)

developer@cn-vm-yourname:~/Desktop/kramdeni/v
```

and my expected output is to print only all values without keys in required order.

To get above result I wrote groovy script like below :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

label = "test testname params"

def jsonFile = new File('PARAMS.json')
def par = new JsonSlurper().parse(jsonFile)
println keys.keySet()

def command = ""
keys = label.split(" ")
println "keys: " + keys

for (key in keys) {
    command += par[key] + " "  
}
println "command: " + command
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to share screen shot? And what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def src = new File("MYPATH/MY.json")
//next line downloads json from URL:
//def src = new URL("http://date.jsontest.com")

def json = new JsonSlurper().parse( src.newInputStream() )

json.each{ k,v->  println "$k = $v" }
```

try it:

https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/#?load=ccceffd570c6ee176bc6f1fcdafdcbe0

---

if you have exception

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
  groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types:
    (java.io.BufferedInputStream)
  Possible solutions: parse(java.io.Reader) ...
```

that means you have quite old version of groovy, however it suggests solution - try to get reader from file:

```
def src = new File("MYPATH/MY.json")
def json = new JsonSlurper().parse( src.newReader("UTF-8") )
json.each{ k,v->  println "$k = $v" }
```

but to continue you have to find version of your groovy, then find documentation for your version and continue developing referencing it

for example in groovy 1.8.6 there are only two `parse` methods in JsonSlurper:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/1.8.6/html/api/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html

and in the latest groovy much more...

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html

Comment: I have tried above one  also but still getting the same error, and one more point I want to add that my PARAMS.json script prasent like : . var()dir in that I have my PARAMS.json file and parseJSON.groovy file

Comment: Getting error after trying above code :{ No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [jsonFile]}

Comment: Can any one please help, I am unable to move forward in my coding ?

Comment: It seems you try to quote `new JsonSlurper().parse( "jsonFile" )` but you should use `jsonFile` without quotes: `new JsonSlurper().parse( jsonFile )`

Comment: Thanks for reply daggett,but it is not working without quotes also

Comment: @Krishnaveni, i've added online test example that downloads json from URL: https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/#?load=ccceffd570c6ee176bc6f1fcdafdcbe0